# Develop gem locally and invalidate cache

Tags: rubygems

I am working on a gem, and using the local path syntax:

```
gem 'mygem', path: '/mypath'
```

However, when i edit the gem, my changes do not apply unless i build a new version of the gem and then call `bundle install`

Is there a way to flush the cache or otherwise ignore it when developing a gem locally?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same situation.

Just remove `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install` (or just `bundle`).

After `bundle install` the changes are applied.